# Propositional Logic questions about tableau method

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Hello i am learning for my exam from logic, I came across the question which i don't know how to solve it.

Can tableau for a propositional formula containing an infinite path exist?
Can be tableau for a propositional formula containing an infinite path finished?
Is tableau for a propositional formula containing an infinite path always finished?

Can you help me with this?

Comment: I'm not quite clear what you mean by "finished" - does this mean that no more rules apply?

Comment: I am not sure but probably yes.

Answer (score 1):

One way of setting up tableaux rules for the propositional calculus requires you to "tick off" a complex wff when you apply the appropriate rule to extract simpler wffs (splitting the tree if necessary), and then you can't revisit ticked off wffs. So as you build the tree, the wffs get simpler, until you run out of complex wffs to apply any more rules to, and the process of tree-building terminates.

So, if that's the way things are set up, then a tableau for a propositional formula can't contain an infinite path.

Suppose alternatively that you are allowed to revisit a complex wff and re-apply a rule, silly though that is, so that a tableau that starts, e.g.

$$\neg (P \lor Q)\\ \neg P\\ \neg Q\\ \neg P\\ \neg Q\\ \neg P\\ \neg Q\\ \ldots$$

is allowed. Then trivially you can have infinite open branches.